# Changing display server in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wayland, display-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Linux kernel 4.15.0.
I've learned that casting the entire screen can't yet be done with Wayland.
Is there any workaround for this, or should I change my display server entirely?
If so, Can someone walk me through changing my display server from Wayland to something else that can support casting a whole screen?

Edit: I'm now able to cast my entire screen, probably due to a patch.

Comment: Wayland is a display server, display managers are different. https://wiki.debian.org/DisplayManager

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thank you.